# Revive dead part of a bush

Tags: shrubs

I had one tree and two bushes next to each other. One of the bushes died as a casualty of some underground pipe work, so I removed it. The other two are bare where they had been up against the third. It's been a few years and those bare spots have not grown back. The other sections of both plants seem to be doing well enough. The bare spots are on the shady (north) side. Is there a way to to bring the bare spots back to life?

Dead parts of tree (arborvitae?) and bush (unknown species)
[image: Dead parts of tree and bush]

Fronts of tree and bush for identification
[image: Front of tree and bush for identification]

Comment: What species of shrubs are they?

Comment: @NiallC. I don't know. Added a picture, if someone can identify I will edit the title. Some kind of evergreen.

Comment: Its very difficult to tell what they are because the photo is poor quality, but they look like they may be coniferous - if they are, dead parts don't regrow n those, but please post a clearer photo if you can

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the picture was so bad until I posted it. I'll get a better one.

Comment: I see that Box wood or Ilex hedge on the left side of your walk and none on the other side.  Ornamental grass, tall would still be wonderful to change the color and texture but in addition to the tall grass, you should  continue that hedge on the other side of the walk.  There are also (same green, same texture) tall Ilex shrubs such as 'Sky Pencil' that would complement the verticals of your porch and columns and fit in that space.  Dunno if you have room, but I'd do 5 or 6.  With a few of the Maiden Hair grass or Karl Forester.  Plant some colorful perennials like Crocosmia or Canna?

Comment: Your hedge as well as all of your shrubs need to be pruned so that the TOP of the hedge or shrub is narrower than the bottom.  So slightly angled for sun to reach the lower part of the hedge or shrub to ensure the foliage at the bottom doesn't start thinning.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like Arborvitae and a Tam Juniper.  No, there really is not a way to get them to revive at these spots.  If you were to prune so that the tops are narrower than the bottoms of these shrubs that would help a bit but these shrubs are quite mature and this looks like their shady side.  I'd get a soft, deciduous shrub to fill that space such as a bridal veil spiraea planted at least 3 or 4 feet away from these two shrubs.

What I am worried about is a fairly horrid disease called phytophthora which affects arborvitae an awful lot.  The juniper is bare just because of lack of sun.  Tell us more about the arborvitae you lost, what did you notice first, how long did it take for complete kill?  Phytophthora is still in that soil.  Watch the rest of your arborvitae closely.  Take pics and send.  Or get a soil sample and send to your nearest cooperative extension service (part of a University in your area).

Comment: Why do you suspect phytophthora is in the soil?

Comment: *"died as a casualty of some underground pipe work"* is not a disease, so that's a long jump, stormy.

Comment: Not seen many mature plants die from pipe work, I have seen lots of arborvitae die from phytophthora.  Most 'pipe work' is usually 1" irrigation pipe and should not bother much of anything.  If this is sewer lines or main water lines, sure.  Phytophthora is odd because JUST one plant dies and then another...etc.  And it could easily come from the shoes of the dudes fixing the pipe from another property.  Otherwise, sure it is a long jump, grins!!

Comment: The pipe work was a few years ago. I think if one of these two was going to die of it, it would have done so by now.

Comment: I don't know about planting any shrub between the existing shrubbery and the porch.  That would be a tight squeeze.

Comment: This would be a perfect spot for Miscanthus gracillus, Maiden Hair grass or even Karl Forester Reed Grass.  Soft, no hard edges, easy to maintain.  I gave my answer before second picture...makes sense.

Comment: @J.Musser the shrub that was removed was roughly the size of the hypothetical juniper. There's plenty of space to plant something else. The hedge in the background is a boxwood and is unrelated to my post.